# (Javascript) Google Sign-In for websites not working

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I put this in the < head > section:

```
<!-- Google Authentication -->
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var auth2;
    var initClient = function() {
        gapi.load('auth2', function(){
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '*********.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                fetch_basic_profile : false,
                scope : 'profile'
            });
            auth2.then(function(){
                if (auth2.isSignedIn.get() == true) {
                    auth2.signIn();
                }
            })
            auth2.then(function(){
              if (!auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
                    location.href("index.html")
              }
        }
        });
    };
</script>
```

But the "location.href("index.html") is never reached. Anyone know why?

If i put location.href(...) just above the .init(...) function, it will be reached. But if I put it just below it will not work. So the error is within the .init() function but I can't find out what it is

(the result of auth2.isSignedIn.get() is "undefined", it should be true or false)

Comment: Try `window.location.href="index.html"`

Comment: Not working. But the error is not the "location.href(...)" line itself...if I move it above the function it works...It is the load or init code that is faulty, I'm missing something...

Comment: Tried stepping through the code?

Comment: I think multiple then() function will not work. Try with single then() function

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auth2;
    var initClient = function() {
        gapi.load('auth2', function(){
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '*********.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                fetch_basic_profile : false,
                scope : 'profile'
            });
            auth2.then(()=>{
                if (auth2.isSignedIn.get() == true) {
                    auth2.signIn();
                } else{
                     window.location.href="index.html";
                  }
            })

        }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I'm thankful but it does not work. The location.href() line is never reached even if i'm not logged in

Comment: Have you consoled  `auth2.isSignedIn` object inside then() function ?

Comment: Can't understand o.O what to you mean by "consoled"?

Comment: put this statement `console.log(auth2.isSignedIn)` inside then() and see the output in console

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=initLoad" async defer></script>
<script>
    try{
        window.initLoad = function(){
            gapi.load('auth2', function(){
                var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: '********.apps.googleusercontent.com'
                });
                if (auth2.isSignedIn.get() == true) {
                    auth2.signIn();
                }else{
                    window.location.assign("index.html");
                }
            });
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err.message);
    }
</script>
```

Now I've a new issue, the Login button does no more work...It is on another page and I've touched nothing but ok, new issues all the day...

Comment: Good to know that fixed. Post a new question if you have more issues. :)